# React-js and Typescript - Convert connect() to useSelect, useDispatch()

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

who can help me to convert this code that I use connect () to use useSelect() and useDistpatch(), with reactjs-redux and typescript. Thanks

```
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
      onAddUser: (user: UserResponse) => {
        dispatch(addUser(user))
      }
    })
    
    export default connect(
      null,
      mapDispatchToProps
    )(AddUser)
```

and

```
    const UsersLists = ({ users, onDelete }: any) => (
      <div>
        {users.map((user: any) => (
          <DeleteUser key={user.id} onDelete={onDelete} user={user} />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => ({
      bookmarks: state
    })

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  onDelete: (id: number) => {
    dispatch(deleteUser(id))
  }
})

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(UsersLists)
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverflow, Are you using `Redux Toolkit` in your application?

Comment: Hi.. mm redux-Toolkit, no, but no no problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd still use the container pattern as it offers a good separation of concerns between presentation and wiring and thus simplifies testing:

```
type UserListProps = {
    users: IUser[];
    onAdd: (user: IUser) => void;
    onDelete: (user: IUser) => void;
};

const UsersLists = (props: UserListProps) => {
    const { users } = props;

    return (
        <div>
            {users.map((user: any) => (
                <DeleteUser
                    key={user.id}
                    onDelete={props.onDelete}
                    user={user}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

and for the container:

```
export const UsersListsContainer = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const users = useSelector(selectors.$users);
    const bookmarks = useSelector(selectors.$bookmarks);

    const onAddUser = useCallback(
        (user: IUser) => {
            dispatch(actions.addUser(user));
        },
        [dispatch]
    );

    const onDeleteUser = useCallback(
        (user: IUser) => {
            dispatch(actions.deleteUser(user.id));
        },
        [dispatch]
    );

    return (
        <UserLists
            users={users}
            bookmarks={bookmarks}
            onAddUser={onAddUser}
            onDeleteUser={onDeleteUser}
        />
    );
};
```